# YouTube videos does not work in full screen in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

Fresh install Ubuntu 20.04 on Matebook X Pro with Intel UHD620. I have display scale set to 175%.

When clicking f or full screen button I get a quarter of the screen as black and see the desktop and other apps outside this quarter screen.

In Chromium I get the video playing on the quarter of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that it's caused by turning off "Use system title bar and borders" in Chrome. Enabling this makes it work normally. 
I also switched to using Wayland and it works perfect in Wayland! Even with "Use system title bar and borders" disabled.

Scaling settings did not matter.

Comment: Please come back in 25 hours and mark your own answer as accepted by clicking the gray checkmark beside it. It will change color from gray to green when you click it.

Comment: I just came across this post and tried turning on the setting, and it worked!

But what was truly interesting was that I turned the setting off again, and Youtube fullscreen still works!

To summarize, I think this is the state of events that triggered and fixed the bug for me:

1. Enable fractional scaling;
2. Youtube fullscreen was broken;
3. Disable fractional scaling;
4. Youtube fullscreen still broken;
5. Enable "Use system titlebar and borders";
6. Youtube fullscreen fixed;
7. Disable "Use system titlebar and borders";
8. Youtube fullscreen still works normally

Answer (score 0):

Fractional scaling is a new, and perhaps to an extent still immature feature. The issue you see is most probably related to using fractional scaling. If the current issue is a problem, you may need to move away from fractional scaling until current limitations and issues like this have been fixed.

You may want to revert to 100% scaling. You can then apply a scaling factor to enlarge system fonts. Use Gnome Tweaks (Fonts tab) for that. In all browsers, you also can set a scaling factor for the display of web sites. This way, you likely will be able to achieve a pleasing appearance, avoiding the issue of full screen playback that you experience when using the fractional scaling.

At this time, fractional scaling needs more more computer resources. Thus, sticking to 100% scaling may also make for a smoother experience as it is less taxing on your computer.